# Draw a square with the help of the for loop in Python tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I want to draw 8 frames per side by using the for loop in Tkinter. First one white and then one black (like a chessboard).

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("pyChess")
window.geometry("523x523+250+0")
window.configure( background = 'brown')

x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 65
y2 = 65
j1 = 65
k1 = 0
j2 = 130
k2 = 65

for i in range(8):
      i = Canvas(window, width=520, height=1000)
      i.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")
      x1 += 130
      x2 += 130
      i.create_rectangle(j1, k1, j2, k2, fill="black")
      j1 += 130
      j2 += 130

i.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I wrote this code, but it didn't give me eight frames. It just opened a blank screen. What can I do for it?

Comment: Why do you create 8 canvases?  Just create one canvas is enough.  And your code will only show the last canvas created because you call pack() outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the *x1, x2, j1, j2* values for each `Canvas` widget. Either you draw all rectangles on the **same** Canvas (fow which the values of x1, x2, j1 and j2 need to be updated) or grid multiple Canvas widgets on each row.

Try the following code (rectangles are drawn only for the **first row**):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()    
window.title("pyChess")    
window.geometry("523x523+250+0")
window.configure( background = 'grey')

x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 65
y2 = 65
j1 = 65
k1 = 0
j2 = 130
k2 = 65
a = [0 , 1, 2, 3]

for x,i in enumerate(a):
    i = Canvas(window, width=130, height=65)
    i.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white")
    i.create_rectangle(j1, k1, j2, k2, fill="black")
    i.grid(row = 0, column = x)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `for x in range(4)` instead of `for x,i in enumerate(a)`.